# SQL doing a groupby on top of another groupby

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

**I have these 2 tables:**

```
+---------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+---------+
| items_ordered |             |                     |          |         |
+---------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+---------+
| customerid    | order_date  | item                | quantity | price   |
| 10330         | 30-Jun-1999 | Pogo stick          | 1        | 28.00   |
| 10101         | 30-Jun-1999 | Raft                | 1        | 58.00   |
| 10298         | 01-Jul-1999 | Skateboard          | 1        | 33.00   |
| 10101         | 01-Jul-1999 | Life Vest           | 4        | 125.00  |
| 10299         | 06-Jul-1999 | Parachute           | 1        | 1250.00 |
| 10339         | 27-Jul-1999 | Umbrella            | 1        | 4.50    |
| 10449         | 13-Aug-1999 | Unicycle            | 1        | 180.79  |
| 10439         | 14-Aug-1999 | Ski Poles           | 2        | 25.50   |
| 10101         | 18-Aug-1999 | Rain Coat           | 1        | 18.30   |
| 10449         | 01-Sep-1999 | Snow Shoes          | 1        | 45.00   |
| 10439         | 18-Sep-1999 | Tent                | 1        | 88.00   |
| 10298         | 19-Sep-1999 | Lantern             | 2        | 29.00   |
| 10410         | 28-Oct-1999 | Sleeping Bag        | 1        | 89.22   |
| 10438         | 01-Nov-1999 | Umbrella            | 1        | 6.75    |
| 10438         | 02-Nov-1999 | Pillow              | 1        | 8.50    |
| 10298         | 01-Dec-1999 | Helmet              | 1        | 22.00   |
| 10449         | 15-Dec-1999 | Bicycle             | 1        | 380.50  |
| 10449         | 22-Dec-1999 | Canoe               | 1        | 280.00  |
| 10101         | 30-Dec-1999 | Hoola Hoop          | 3        | 14.75   |
| 10330         | 01-Jan-2000 | Flashlight          | 4        | 28.00   |
| 10101         | 02-Jan-2000 | Lantern             | 1        | 16.00   |
| 10299         | 18-Jan-2000 | Inflatable Mattress | 1        | 38.00   |
| 10438         | 18-Jan-2000 | Tent                | 1        | 79.99   |
| 10413         | 19-Jan-2000 | Lawnchair           | 4        | 32.00   |
| 10410         | 30-Jan-2000 | Unicycle            | 1        | 192.50  |
| 10315         | 2-Feb-2000  | Compass             | 1        | 8.00    |
| 10449         | 29-Feb-2000 | Flashlight          | 1        | 4.50    |
| 10101         | 08-Mar-2000 | Sleeping Bag        | 2        | 88.70   |
| 10298         | 18-Mar-2000 | Pocket Knife        | 1        | 22.38   |
| 10449         | 19-Mar-2000 | Canoe paddle        | 2        | 40.00   |
| 10298         | 01-Apr-2000 | Ear Muffs           | 1        | 12.50   |
| 10330         | 19-Apr-2000 | Shovel              | 1        | 16.75   |
```

+---------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+---------+

```
+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+----------------+---+
| customers  |           |          |              |                |   |
+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+----------------+---+
| customerid | firstname | lastname | city         | state          |   |
| 10101      | John      | Gray     | Lynden       | Washington     |   |
| 10298      | Leroy     | Brown    | Pinetop      | Arizona        |   |
| 10299      | Elroy     | Keller   | Snoqualmie   | Washington     |   |
| 10315      | Lisa      | Jones    | Oshkosh      | Wisconsin      |   |
| 10325      | Ginger    | Schultz  | Pocatello    | Idaho          |   |
| 10329      | Kelly     | Mendoza  | Kailua       | Hawaii         |   |
| 10330      | Shawn     | Dalton   | Cannon Beach | Oregon         |   |
| 10338      | Michael   | Howell   | Tillamook    | Oregon         |   |
| 10339      | Anthony   | Sanchez  | Winslow      | Arizona        |   |
| 10408      | Elroy     | Cleaver  | Globe        | Arizona        |   |
| 10410      | Mary Ann  | Howell   | Charleston   | South Carolina |   |
| 10413      | Donald    | Davids   | Gila Bend    | Arizona        |   |
| 10419      | Linda     | Sakahara | Nogales      | Arizona        |   |
| 10429      | Sarah     | Graham   | Greensboro   | North Carolina |   |
| 10438      | Kevin     | Smith    | Durango      | Colorado       |   |
| 10439      | Conrad    | Giles    | Telluride    | Colorado       |   |
| 10449      | Isabela   | Moore    | Yuma         | Arizona        |   |
+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+----------------+---+
```

**What I am trying to do is be able to sum the total amount of price by each state. This will sum up the total price spent by customers according to their location. But I can't manage to figure how you do it in SQL. What I was able to do is get a list of states by userid multiple times to get the table below:**

---

```
+-----------------+-------+---------+
| Arizona         | 10339 | 4.50    |
| Arizona         | 10449 | 970.79  |
| Arizona         | 10298 | 147.88  |
| Arizona         | 10413 | 128.00  |
| Colorado        | 10439 | 139.00  |
| Colorado        | 10438 | 95.24   |
| Oregon          | 10330 | 156.75  |
| Sourth Carolina | 10410 | 281.72  |
| Washington      | 10299 | 1288.00 |
| Washington      | 10101 | 813.95  |
| Wisconsin       | 10315 | 8.00    |
+-----------------+-------+---------+
```

### I used the following operation to get the taable above:

```
>   SELECT c.State, i.customerid, SUM(i.quantity * i.price)   
>   FROM items_ordered i, customers c
>   WHERE c.customerid = i.customerid   
>   GROUP BY i.customerid
>   ORDER BY c.State;
```

Below is the table that I'm trying to get to be displayed:

```
+-----------------+-------+---------+
| Arizona         | 10339 | 1251.17 |
| Colorado        | 10438 | 234.24  |
| Oregon          | 10330 | 156.75  |
| Sourth Carolina | 10410 | 281.72  |
| Washington      | 10299 | 2101.95 |
| Wisconsin       | 10315 | 8.00    |
+-----------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Added `mysql` tag due to the non-standard (invalid) `group by` usage.

Comment: Are all your columns VARCHAR !?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for GROUP BY for the database you are using.

Changing the GROUP BY to be on `c.state` should give you what I think you are after:

```
SELECT c.State, SUM(i.quantity * i.price) AS `total_amount`
   FROM items_ordered i, customers c
   WHERE c.customerid = i.customerid
   GROUP BY c.State ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db7f0f/4)

Answer (score 0):

You want to sum by state - so just remove the customer id from the select list and group by state instead:

```
SELECT   c.State, SUM(i.quantity * i.price)   
FROM     items_ordered i, customers c
WHERE    c.customerid = i.customerid   
GROUP BY c.State
```